# React-Native app is crashing on launch after adding react-native-admob module

Tags: react-native, admob

Below is my package.

`{
  "name": "wallpaper_rn",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2",
    "react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.11.17",
    "react-native-share": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.14.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "recyclerlistview": "^1.3.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
}`

I also tried react-native-admob (1.3.2) version.

I just installed admob module and link it. After that app suddenly started crashing on launch even in debug mode.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for your crash?

Comment: @halfer
Sorry ..., Next time I will take all this considerations before making a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I understand that Google at October 2nd, 2018 updates some libraries that caused this error. I changed android/build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
```

and this has solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Sanket Lathiya

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line in your project `AndroidManifest.xml`

inside `<application>`

```js
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="[appid here]"/>
```

Reference: https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/issues/370#issuecomment-429322754